# What's your "remember me" cookie's lifetime?

Tags: cookies, language-agnostic

My spec says 30 days. I am about to argue for quite a longer TTL, something like 90 - 120 days. What do you think?

This is for a standard website, not an intranet app.

Comment: I can never keep cookies around for more than two or three days...

Comment: I agree in principle, but doesn't such a short ttl go against remember me's logic?

Comment: Is there any reason to have it expire?

Comment: @Gabe: Well, I can't think of a reason to expire such a trivial cookie, other than to not have our security expert shoot me in the foot.

Comment: @James: It's 8 am here (gr) and still haven't had my coffee :)

Comment: @Yannis - yeah, security experts with guns are a nuisance to the society. but at least yours is aiming at the foot. mine are usually going for a control shot in the head. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My personal advice would be to do it as a combination of relatively-short expiration cookie with sliding expiration and a long expiration identity cookie.

The first part is your standard week/month-long expiration authentication ticket cookie, which you renew on each request or at certain time interval, or whatever other sliding expiration scheme you want to employ.

The second part is you remember the identity of the user in a half year/year-expiration cookie. This is not an authentication ticket, just an identity reminder, so that if the user returns *after* their session has expired, they get greeted and you might choose to show some non-sensitive personal information, like number of emails in inbox or anything like that, but to actually access any sensitive information, they need to authenticate themselves.

This will give your regular users (visiting every day or week) continuous never-expiring session, while still keeping the authentication tickets with relatively short time frame. At the same time, for people that return after more than a month, you can still give them a personalized experience, yet their account is secure. I don't think anyone would actually have a problem, if you ask them to authenticate to access certain parts of their account after a month of absence, even if they'd checked the remember me/remember my password checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

**It Depends** is the most natural answer. Additionally, we should also ask the user if it's a personal laptop or shared workstation or a public machine.

If Is it a social network or a mail portal or something similar than 2 weeks. in case of personal workstation >4 weeks. If it's a banking system then there's nothing like Remember Me and persistent auth. In fact session should be terminated for no activity in last 15 minutes.

So **It depends**.

Comment: Some clarification: It's a standard website, no financial data are stored (not an eshop / bank), just common contact info. 

My last banking app terminated the session in 10 mins, I'm a little more paranoid than you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its depends upon whos using the system. If its an employee of a company using his assigned computer regularly and one of the intranet site sets up "remember me" cookie it can be longer a year or more.

Comment: Nope, this is for a standard website :)